# Facing access denied while accessing the azure fabric explorer 403

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric

I am deploying azure fabric cluster referring the Microsoft docs
on deploying the cluster using  service fabric explorer getting "Access to srvfabric.cloudapp.azure.com was denied" You don't have the user right to view the page
HTTP error 403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I deployed the SFC cluster, Even I got the same **error code** as yours:-

[image]

Make sure your key vault certificate used to create the SFC cluster is correct with your SFC domain name added as common name CN like below:-

[image]

Download the above certificate as pfx in your local machine and import it in your cert-manager like below:-

[image]

Type ***certmgr.msc.*** as a run command and open certificate manager and import this certificate from your local machine like below:-

Click on Personal > certificates > All tasks > import > Import the certificate from your local folder by selecting the path below:-

[image]

[image]

Click next > next > Password is not required and import the certificate.

The certificate will be imported like below:-

[image]

While creating the Service Fabric, I Added the above certificate for authentication like below:-

[image]

[image]

Certificate added after SFC deployment:-

[image]

Now, ***Browse the URL from the Overview tab and if you receive an error related to Your connection is not private > Choose the advance tab and Proceed > If it prompts for a certificate > Select the certificate you imported in the step above > You will be routed to the SFC explorer successfully like below:-***

[image]

[image]

***SFC Explorer page loaded successfully:-***

[image]

Comment: For me i downloaded the cert from azure key vault and placed on the azure VM.Then import the cert on browser it works